# Move firefox 13 menu bar to global menu bar in Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, firefox, globalmenu

I am using Firefox 13 in Ubuntu 12.04.

How can I access the Firefox 13 menu in Unity's global menu bar? I am using to the whole Firefox menu appearing when I hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install Firefox? I'm using Firefox 13 on Ubuntu 12.04 and the menu bar appears on Unity (this is called "global menu bar"). This is done with an addon called firefox-globalmenu. If you somehow installed Firefox from a non-ubuntu package, that may be the problem.

You can try opening a terminal and typing

`sudo apt-get install firefox-globalmenu`

this will either install the package or tell you that it's already installed.

Comment: I've also found that the plugin stopped working when Firefox was upgraded (through the official PPA).